My python bluesky bot fails to when running Client.login
I have a bluesky bot that posts once an hour. It's been running for months without a problem. A couple days ago it started failing when running the Client login method using the username and passowrd.
I am aware of the rate-limiting for logging in that way, but once an hour and only 24 times a day is way under the upper limits.
A day or so ago I started getting this error when I try to log in via my bot script:
BadRequestError: 
Response(
    success=False, 
    status_code=400, 
    content=XrpcError(error='InvalidRequest', message='Profile not found'), 
    headers={
        'x-powered-by': 'Express', 
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 
        'cache-control': 'private', 
        'vary': 'Authorization, Accept-Encoding', 
        'ratelimit-limit': '3000', 
        'ratelimit-remaining': '2998', 
        'ratelimit-reset': '1725317047', 
        'ratelimit-policy': '3000;w=300', 
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
        'content-length': '56', 
        'etag': 'W/"38-tAZLZU2ZqXXtTINJ8yohUtX3PCk"', 
        'date': 'Mon, 02 Sep 2024 22:39:26 GMT', 
        'keep-alive': 'timeout=90', 
        'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000'
    }
)

As I said, this code:
from atproto import Client

client = Client()
client.login(<username>, <password>)

Was working fine a few days ago and now it throws this error. I haven't seen anything on the Google posted in the last few days about anyone else having this issue.
Edited to add:

I also tried using an app password, but that fails too.
I can log into the account on the bsky.app, so the "Profile not found" portion of the error seems like a red herring.

Edited again to add:

I tried logging in to my main account using the atproto library and that worked fine. I think that I have exceeded some max number of logins or something.

